# Cannot change Android Studio Logcat colors

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following a few tutorials in order to change my Logcat colors in Android Studio 0.6.1 without success.

To set it up I go to:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colours and Fonts -> Android Logcat

Once on Android Logcat, the foreground, background, etc. check boxes are all disabled.

Does anyone have an idea why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off the topic but there is more convenient Android log tool: https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat. Colours could be changed in the python script.

Comment: I am sorry, I am starting. I cannot find help in others webs with this question.

Comment: There is a check-box below the all available color options Entitled "Inherit Attributes From Console", Untick that checkbox will enable all color options for you .

Comment: Yes @pyus13 works:
1.-Click on "save as"
2.-Write your color scheme
3.-Untick checkbox
4.-Select your colors

Comment: Wow great, As it helped I included it same in to the answer ho help others too. After all we all are here for that only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot change the default so first you need to creat your own configuration by clicking on "save as" button.

After doing so there is a check-box below the all available color options, Entitled "Inherit Attributes From Console", Untick that checkbox will enable all color options for you.

Answer (score 16):

To change the **Logcat** colors you can go to goto **File > Settings** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

You can see this similar UI assuming you are using **Darcula Theme**
[image]

Note you need to unchecked **Use inherited attributes** in-order to modify the color.

[image]